# no end point listening at demo.docusign.net exception

Tags: docusignapi

I have a demo account and integrator key.  I added a reference to https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/api.asmx?wsdl from Visual Studio.

Trying the same code from  C# cook book... When I call `CreateAndSendEnvelope` method, it is giving "remote host can not be resolved."

Is there anything that I need to do in Docusign Console? Like preferences?

```
DocuSignAPI.EnvelopeStatus status = proxy.CreateAndSendEnvelope(envelope);
```

CreateAndSendEnvelope throws "There is no end point listening at demo.docusign.net" see inner exception for more details. Inner exception is "Remote Host can not be resolved

Comment: Please show the problematic code snippet and the exact errors you're getting in your error log.

Comment: DocuSignAPI.EnvelopeStatus
status
= proxy.CreateAndSendEnvelope(envelope);
CreateandSendEnvelope throws "There is no end point listening at demo.docusign.net " see inner exception for more detais. Inner exception is " Remote Host can not be resolved "

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code. Please show the complete code including the server url used.

Answer (score 0):

"remote host can not be resolved." most of the time means that you do not have connectivity from your application.  All the basic connectivity things should be tested:

1. try using your browser from within your network
2. try running curl or something else that's not a browser because browsers sometimes auto-configure proxies
3. try other services from your code like Google API's (Drive, Maps, whatever)

Basically I am 99% sure that this problem is a proxy/firewall/connectivity issue and that you are not even reaching DocuSign demo servers from your app.